# I need help in understanding this phrase

Tags: meaning, phrases

would you explain the meaning of this phrase please :

> "And in this video we looked at some common speed reading techniques
>   and showed how
>   ***they're really not as effective as a lot of people want to believe they are***."

the meaning and if there is a grammar rule here :

> "***they're really not as effective as a lot of people want to believe
>   they are***."

and thank you,

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand about the phrase?  Which bit of it is troubling you?  It seems clear enough to me.

Comment: Since people's beliefs and desires seem to be very closely linked, ('[A] man hears what he wants to hear, and disregards the rest.': S&G) "... they're really not as effective as a lot of people believe they are." would seem to suffice and is quite possibly true. However, the original points out that 'believe' and 'want to believe' are not in principle identical, and also uses a hedged form (... "they're really not as effective as a lot of people would like to believe they are." is another hedged form).

Comment: It means that (a) a lot of people believe that the techniques are effective; but (b) in fact, these techniques are not effective - at least not as effective as people think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And in this video we looked at some common speed reading techniques and shows how ***they're really not as effective as a lot of people want to believe they are.***

***they*** in ***they're*** refers to *some common speed reading techniques*.

***they're really not as effective as a lot of people want to believe they are.*** means that *a lot of people want to believe* that *common speed reading techniques* are *effective*, when *common speed reading techniques* are not as *effective* as *a lot of people want to believe they are*.

In other words a lot of people believe that common speed reading techniques are effective. In this video it showed that common speed reading techniques are not as efficient as a lot of people believed.

Comment: "*a lot of people want to believe that common speed reading techniques are effective, when they truly believe that they are not.*" No. *Want to believe* here is the same as *believe*. The contrast is not between what they want to believe vs. what they truly believe - it is between what they believe vs. the actual facts.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: I have upvoted this to offset the malicious anonymous downvote.

Comment: @cherryblossom thanks a lot my friends you solved my problem

Comment: @michael.hor257k  thank you brother